# Non-attacking knights and rooks on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, puzzle, chessboard

This question from math contest *olympiad phystech* I tried to find the solution but I can't find it. Please help me to find solution of this problem.
**Given a board with a size of $11 × 11$ cells. Jack wants to put $N$ of rooks and $2N$ of horses on the board so that none of the pieces beats any other. At what greatest $N$ can he do this?**

Comment: none of the pieces $\color{red}{\text{beats}}$ any other. Do you mean attacks ?

Comment: Is this an active contest?  Please provide a link to the contest itself.

Comment: @lulu no, this is an option of past years

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit yes exactly

Comment: (This may sound trivial, but in case someone wants a starting point: the canonical name of the problem of which this is a generalisation is the *non-attacking rooks* (resp. *knights*) problem)

Comment: @eru-cs 
Yes, that’s understandable, but I can’t find **N**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the $N$ rooks take away $N$ ranks and $N$ files, only $(11-N)^2\ge2N$ squares are remaining for the knights. $N=8$ leaves only $9$ squares, but $N=7$ leaves $16$, which is enough. Put rooks on c5, d4, e3, f6, g9, h8, and i7 and you could put knights on a1, a2, b1, b2, a10, a11, b10, b11, j1, j2, k1, k2, j10, j11, k10, and k11 and satisfy all constraints.

**EDIT**: Actually on a $k\times k$ board with $N$ rooks where $k\le2N+1\le2k+1$ you can always find squares for the $(k-N)^2$ knights: first fill the black long diagonal with rooks, then remove every other rook until only $N$ are left. All squares occupied by rooks or available to knights are now black squares so the knights, attacking only white squares, can't attack anything. E.g. on a $17\times17$ board put rooks on a1, b2, c3, d4, e5, f6, g7, h8, i9, j10, k11, l12, m13, n14, o15, p16, and q17. Then remove the a1, c3, e5, g7, and i9 rooks and you have $25$ black squares you can put knights on.

Comment: Thanks for the decision, but I did not understand that inequality is how you came to this?

Comment: There are only $11-N$ ranks and $11-N$ files remaining to put knights on, thus a total of $(11-N)^2$ squares available. The problem statement required placing $2N$ knights, so the number of available squares must be at least the number of knights. After that it's a question of finding a placement of the pieces. Originally I was going to put all the rooks on the long diagonal from c3 to i9 but a knight on b1 would attack the c3 rook so I had to adjust the positions of the rooks near the corners.

Comment: brilliant! thanks a lot. now everything is clear!!!